# Is there a downside to huge arrays for quick data retrieval?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a huge (I think) array of 5000 x 750 x 10. I use it to quickly retrieve data for a given stock on a given date. I've found recordsets take way longer since you have to "seek" each line before you can retrieve the data. Is there a downside to such a large array besides the initial populating time?

Comment: Iterating an array is, worst-case, O(n) - i.e. you iterate *every* item to get the one you want. Contrast with a `Dictionary` keyed with the concatenation of a stock ticker and a date: retrieval is essentially a O(1) hash lookup, i.e. essentially free. And if the data lives in an actual database, having the server perform the filtering/querying and returning the one result row in a recordset could actually be even faster than anything else, assuming a decent network and proper indexes. TL;DR: way too many variables, there's no silver bullet. The only proper answer is `#ItDepends`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify, I have index tables for the date, stock, and price type. For example, the code would retrieve the volume(5) for AAPL(15) on 9/19/2019(4994) with myData(15, 4994, 5). There is no iterating involved except for initially populating the array from all of the stock data files, which takes about 15 seconds. I'm running monte carlo simulations that runs for up to several hours to days so the 15 second load time is nothing.

Comment: If the array is working for you then it seems like a good solution, as long as the load time is offset by improved access speed.  It's not clear what type of "recordset" implementation you're comparing that to though.

Comment: The DAO recordset declaration available in VBA for Access. In this specific case it seemed to be slower since I had to use the .seek option to activate each record. I asked because I am lacking in the "theory" of various data retrieval techniques. My concern with the large array was that it would slow down overall performance because a large chunk of memory is dedicated to it. Sounds like I'm fine based on the two responses. BTW - I know I could test this by running code both ways and I appreciate you helping me learn the theory without wasting days testing.